# How to use data binding with "when" onClickListener in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I use earlier ButterKnife library. This is how I used the click event on multiple objects.

```
@OnClick({ R.id.door1, R.id.door2, R.id.door3 })
public void pickDoor(DoorView door) {
  if (door.hasPrizeBehind()) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You win!", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  } else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Try again", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

Without ButterKnife;

```
 override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when (v!!.id) {
            R.id.tv -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You are click textview", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            R.id.btn -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You are click button.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            else -> {
            }
        }
    }
```

Click the process what I can do. I want to do this with switch or when. Sounds like bad code writing individual setOnClickListener.

```
   binding.btnFive.setOnClickListener { MyLog.log("five") }
//or
        btnFour.setOnClickListener { MyLog.log("four") }
```

But i use now data binding. How do I do this with data binding?

What I was looking for;

```
when(binding){ //of course, this doesn't work. exemplary.
btnFirst->{}
btnSecond->{}
}
```

So I don't want to have to write `setOnClickListener{}` so consistently. How do I do this?

Comment: i still cant find what i am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

To get `View` id you have to call `binding.btn.id`. But data binding suggests to use `ViewModel` and and handling on click inside layout.xml

```
<Button
  .....
  android:onClick="@{()-> viewModel.btnClick()}"
  ..../>
```

You can find explanation at [developer docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding)

Comment: binding.btnFive.setOnClickListener { MyLog.log("five") } btnFour.setOnClickListener { MyLog.log("four") } Click the process what I can do. I want to do this with switch or when. Sounds like bad code writing individual setOnClickListener.

Answer (score 1):

Just same as without butterknife onClick code snippet

---

android {
    ...
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

---

Only change

### setContentView(layout_id) to  DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, layout_id)

and in xml 

Put your xml  in this tag

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding

Comment: binding.btnFive.setOnClickListener { MyLog.log("five") }
        btnFour.setOnClickListener { MyLog.log("four") } Click the process what I can do.I want to do this with switch or when. Sounds like bad code writing individual setOnClickListener.

Comment: No need to declare setOnClickListener  for each, Just use onClick tag in XML.

Answer (score 0):

first at kotlin you don't need any assigning view from layout you can use direct id as view which setcontentview.